# Get CodeSpaces VS Code to apply correct indentation

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, indentation, github-codespaces

I have checked every setting I can think of, but I must be missing something, as when I hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>, I get a 2-space indent, not a 4-space indent when trying to write Python in Visual Studio Code in [GitHub Codespaces](https://github.com/features/codespaces).

This makes me sad. Please see the images of settings and the result. Is there a solution?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What does [the "indentation" status box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/riL6M.png) at the bottom of the IDE say?

Comment: It says 4. However settings.json had 2, from the repo creator. eeesh.

Comment: https://imgur.com/gme0wie.png, Check if there is another value in [Workspace Settings (JSON)](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_workspace-settings).